# How can I find a list of parents with jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I get a list of parents that contain a 'thing'? For example, if I have this HTML:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="A container">
      <div>
          <span class="thing">A thing</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div>
  <div class="B container">
      <div>B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="C container">
    <div>
        <span class="thing">C thing 1</span>
    </div>
      <div class="thing">C thing 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want a list of 2 elements (those containers with class A & C)

I was hoping there was a snappy one-liner that looks better than what I am currently doing:

```
var containers = [];
$.each($('.thing'), function(index, value) {
    containers.push($(value).closest('.container')[0])
});
console.log($.unique(containers));
```

Comment: A class of thing or a string of thing?

Comment: class, the strings are not important. Here's the fiddle, I want the same output, just better: http://jsfiddle.net/Lkcnq3bw/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rather use `:has`  selector:

```
$('.container:has(.thing)').get();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qmazhbkt/)**

Comment: I thought get() was an ajax call, but regardless this is nice.

Comment: Excellent, thought there had to be something!

Answer (score 0):

$.unique($('.thing').parent('.container'))).
We can have a selector in parent () call as well.
This is not tested version.

Comment: This just returns the last container